# How to get the number of "unique" request with splunk

Tags: logging, splunk

We are currently looking for a way to find the number of "unique" request for a given event type with splunk. 
Like the number of user that hit a 404, but i don't care if a user hit it twice or 10 times, I just want the number of user that had that error. 
Is there anyway to do that with splunk ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

Assuming your source type is called "access_combined" and you have a status and user field defined (either by Splunk automatically, or explicitly by you via Field Extraction) your search might look like this:

sourcetype="access_combined" status="404" | dedup user | table user

OR you could try this one as well, which uses the distinct count operation:

sourcetype="access_combined" status="404" | stats dc(status) by user

Comment: Thanks, I actually got a answer on splunk site has well : http://splunk-base.splunk.com/answers/29094/how-to-get-the-number-of-unique-request-with-splunk